# Is it ok to create a transactionService class

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I have some atomic operations in my code. From books that would be a class example.
You withdraw money from one user is the first database access. Then you put that money to another user, would be the second database access operation. Only both together can be executed. If the first succeeds and the second fails, the whole operation has to be rolled back.

So in my application I also have this. Maybe it will never happen but to be sure I made it a transaction.
For example. The user saves its holidays. And also the holiday itself is also saved in another table.

This is my code. I decided to put all transactions in this class. i called it transaction service.
I hope it's ok. I just was a little bit confused when I got an error message there would be 2 transaction manager in my application. I just decided to use the one called transactionManager.

```
@Service
public class TransactionService {

    private UserDao userDao;
    private HolidayDao holidayDao;
    private WorkingMonthDao workingMonthDao;

    @Autowired
    public TransactionService(UserDao userDao,HolidayDao holidayDao,WorkingMonthDao workingMonthDao)
    {
        this.userDao = userDao;
        this.holidayDao = holidayDao;
        this.workingMonthDao = workingMonthDao;
    }

    //@Transactional(isolation=Isolation.READ_COMMITTED, propagation=Propagation.REQUIRED,readOnly=false,timeout=1000, rollbackFor=Exception.class)
    @Transactional(value="transactionManager")
    public void saveUserAndHoliday(User user, Holiday holiday)
    {
        userDao.save(user);     
        holidayDao.save(holiday);
    }

    @Transactional(value="transactionManager")
    public void saveUserAndDeleteHoliday(User user, Holiday holiday)
    {
        holidayDao.delete(holiday);
        userDao.save(user);
    }

    @Transactional(value="transactionManager")
    public void saveUserAndWorkingMonth(User user, WorkingMonth workingMonth)
    {
        userDao.save(user);
        workingMonthDao.save(workingMonth);
    }
}
```

Comment: The problem with this approach is that it does not scale well with the number of combination of operations. What if you need `deleteUserAndDeleteHoliday`, `deleteUserAndDeleteWorkingMonth`, `deleteUserAndSaveWorkingMonth` ... I think there are 20 possible combinations with just save and delete of those 3 entities.

Answer (score 0):

I would give another name to such a service, possibly splitting it into several classes based on business logic domain.
Supposing you are adhere to clean code principles and want to build low coupled application, that can be easily supported in the future.
Transactions are said to belong to [cross-cutting concern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-cutting_concern) of application architecture. That means that transaction related classes should not contain application core logic. Example of such classes could be custom transaction manager. All your methods `saveUserAndHoliday`, `saveUserAndDeleteHoliday` and `saveUserAndWorkingMonth` are responsible for part of a business logic, although small part - combining different DAOs. In my practice we used to call such classes as `Repositories` - intermediate layer between services (core business logic layer) and DAOs (persistance layer).